# How to remove a keyboard shortcut in System Preferences?

Tags: mac, keyboard, shortcut, macos

New to MacBook Pro 2019 (with current OS)

As I am tweaking the hotkeys for my Windows brain, there have been several times I added a key to an entry in System Prefs->Keyboard->Shortcuts but no longer want it.
Some of them have a checkbox to enable/disable;  many do not:
[image: ShortcutKeyToDisable]

Heck, the original value for the circled key assigned was `none`.  :roll-eyes:

I am not willing to 'Restore Default'  -- I want the rest of my changes.
And I do not want to put some garbage key assignment -- that doesn't mesh with my perfectionist personality.  :geek-smiley:

I really wish you could right click any field and it would show you the default value and give option to Restore that (for this field only) or Delete it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250269536 any help?

Comment: Very cool @JLPeyret. 
I no longer have a Mac, but I imagine taking those files would do the trick.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The **Restore Defaults** button only restores the selected item. If the key started out as `none`, simply select the row and click "Restore Defaults".

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked. For fellow visitors, don't forget to select an item before clicking "Restore Defaults". Apparently it's possible to reset the all shortcuts according to the following page. I hope they show some confirmation popup before restoring the all shortcuts, but I'm too afraid to test it: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/keyboard-shortcuts-mchlp2262/mac#:~:text=To%20return%20all%20the%20shortcuts,in%20the%20bottom%2Dleft%20corner.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: assign very difficult and unusual shortcut to what you don't want to use, I usually do the fn key with combination of crazy ones

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Hey brother I know the feeling but the best thing you can do is screenshot what you got already and then restore to defaults and do it again. It sucks brother; I know I've had to restore to default every time I made the smallest mistake. I would suggest putting in a ticket to Apple to add that feature. I personally use the MX 3 mouse and have like 15 shortcuts added to it.

Comment: On the upside, it only resets the current tab & there's only one changed shortcut in that picture. Zoom on/off will revert to 8 instead of 0

Comment: That is good to know @Tetsujin